# How can I append serial number into list

Tags: python-2.7

For example：
I have a list like`['a','b','c','d']` and I tend to use python2.7 add the serial number for my list output should like:

```
[[1,'a'],[2,'b'],[3,'c'],[4,'d']]
```

How can I do this(no other module)?Thanks in advance!

I tend to

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
b = []
for i,item in enumerate(a,start=1):
c = b.append([i,item])
print c
```

but output is `None`

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a code writer service.

Comment: @Mighty Badaboom sorry I update my question now. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> a = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> c = [[i+1, a[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
>>> c
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], [4, 'd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [[x, x] for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4], [5, 5]]
```